# How to read user defined dictionary using shell scripts?

Tags: shell, grep

Say I have a `BCFile` having the following contents:

```
inlet
{
    type            fixedValue;
    value           uniform (5 0 0);
}
outlet
{
    type            inletOutlet;
    inletValue      $internalField;
    value           $internalField;
}
....
blahblahblah (other boundary condition with the same dictionary format as above)
```

In order to print out the type of `outlet` boundary condition, that is `inletOutlet`, I thought I could use,

```
cat BCFile | grep "type" | awk '{printf $2}'  | tr -d ";"
```

But the problem now is in using `grep` there are so many `type` keyword appeared. So is there a way to first detect the word `outlet`, then search and grep the contents between `{}`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWK is pretty powerful. For example if you set the record separator to `}` each block becomes a record of its own. Then you just print the matching record:

```
$ awk -v RS='}' '/outlet/ { print $0 }' file
outlet
{
    type            inletOutlet;
    inletValue      $internalField;
    value           $internalField;
```

Comment: But what if it is `inlet`, since keyword `inlet` occurs many times. This method won't work any more. :(

Comment: There's more than one way to do it: you can change the match condition from `/outlet/` to `/inlet\n{/`, or `$1 ~ /inlet/`, or `/^inlet/`

Answer (score 0):

How about
`grep -A 5 'outlet' BCFile | grep 'type' | awk '{printf $2}' | tr -d ";"`